# Hi everybody, Create table statement in SQL not working!

Tags: oracle

I am a newbie to DBA and I am trying to create a table of vendors and products. Vendor_Name in second line is underlined and when I hover the cursor over it, it shows me a window of error syntax with different lines and I do not understand what they are. After running I receive an error of ORA-00906 "missing left parenthesis."

```
Create Table Vendor (
Vend_ID VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL, Primary Key
Vendor_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Vendor_ST VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
);
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: There's no comma between the `NOT NULL` and the `PRIMARY KEY`! Oracle messages can be a bitch sometimes! p.s. welcome to the forum! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Attention to details is important. Go back to first principles (syntax) if stuck.

```
Create Table Vendor (
Vend_ID VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL primary key,
Vendor_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Vendor_ST VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL
);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4d263c2dc4bbe7fb7df63cc9c6bf78e9)